# how to update div id based on bean value in jsp using jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

how to update div id based on bean value in jsp.
   I will pass listArray from bean. 
   first i will check how many elements presented in listArray
  the Div id should be updated based on the listArray number.
  how can we do in jsp using jstl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood the question.
If you want to print the size of a list using jstl you can try this:

```
<c:out value="${fn:length(listArray)"/>
```

Be sure to declare the fn namespace on your page.

Otherwise, if you want to loop over listArray and create one div per elements (with different id based on current index) you can try this:

```
<c:forEach items="${b.arrayVals}" var="element" varStatus="rowCounter">
   <div id="${rowCounter.count}">${element}</div> 
</c:forEach>
```